# Submitting beta iPhone app to store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

My company is working on a dynamic mobile app that updates the look and appearance based on webcalls and we would like to be able to test that it would be able to get into the store okay. For the time being we have used the code to create an interal company app where the initial screen is a logon screen where the users log in with their company usernames and passwords. There are only about 20 people in the company that will be using this app for the beta release and the app logon is only available to members of the company.

We want to have this test release to first ensure that the app gets into the appstore and secondly to get a feel for the app review process. Would this type of app be allowed into the store? Or due to its limited user group, would they reject it? Also would apple need to be given a test username/pass to login to the company website itself to check how the app runs?

Any information regarding this issue would be very helpful!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) (developer account required):

> If your App looks like it was cobbled together in a few days, or
>   you're trying to get your first practice App into the store to impress
>   your friends, please brace yourself for rejection. We have lots of
>   serious developers who don't want their quality Apps to be surrounded
>   by amateur hour.

and

> **2.9** Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected

Finally, yes, you are required to provide a "demo account" if a login is required to use the entirety of your application.

---

Regarding your small user base, your application may not be accepted if it will only be used by 20 or so people (as stated in the comments). The [iOS Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) is intended for in-house distribution (a small and limited user base).

> **2.22** Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the app ... may be rejected

Comment: This app has been in development for many months, the main part of it is the framework behind the app which is connected through webcalls. We will be using this framework to create dynamic apps for our customers, we just want to ensure the framework gets into the app store, hence the reason we have used this framework to create an app specific to our company for the time being. Would they not be okay then with a small release then, or is an internal only app for around 20 people too small?

Comment: @AdamM If you want to test your app with 20 people, use Xcode to build a IPA file and send it to those 20 people. Regarding your framework, if you followed all of the guidelines and restrictions Apple has provided in the documentation (e.g. no private APIs), it will not be rejected. Do *not* submit test or beta applications to the review team to see if they will be accepted - because they will *not*.

Comment: As I said, the main reason we want to try a release now is to ensure that the framework is accepted into the app store, we have the tested the app already. I just wanted to check if Apple would be okay with release of an app which would only be accessible to a small group of around 20 people

Comment: @AdamM Probably not if the user base is that small - that is what the Enterprise program is intended for - in-house distribution.

Comment: look at my repsponse regarding the small group. You won't know til you try but they have a strict clause in guideline 2.12 and I've seen that rejection before. I second the enterprise program

Comment: Final question then, is there anyway I can check if the app would pass the review process then? As over the next few months we will be working on integrating framework for some of our customers and we just want to be sure that now that it passes all Apples Checks. We don't want to wait until near release time and then suddenly having to spend time trying to figure out why the app was rejected and making all the necessary changes as this would be wasting time.

Comment: @AdamM As I said, if you followed all of the guidelines and restrictions Apple has provided in the documentation (e.g. no private APIs), it will not be rejected for that reason. There is no guarantee that it *will* be accepted, as there may be other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked for a company that did release apps that were secured by a login screen.  All you need to do to get it into the app store is provide Apple with a proper login so that they may test the functionality of the app themselves.  When updating the metadata for your app in iTunes Connect, there is a section for testing notes, simply put your test username/password in there for apple to use.

Answer (score 0):

One way they can reject an app is guideline 2.12: "We found that the features and/or content of your app were not useful or entertaining enough, or your app did not appeal to a broad enough audience, to be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines." If you're concerned about whether or not your app can get to the store, then there is no real problem in just submitting it. Just don't call it a beta test version because they will reject it. If you want, you can always change the release date of the app to a future date once it passes, and then the app will still not be available to all until that future date is reached. And yes you should provide them with a user name